# Entity Framework select column values with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to get column values with group by. My tables are like this:

Table1

```
Id
Material
Length
```

Table2

```
Id
Name
Type
....
..
.
```

I can get plain sql query in a function.

```
public GetValues(tableName, columnName){
    string sql = "select " + columnName + " from " + tableName + " group by " + columnName;
}
```

Is possible doing this via Entity Framework?

Comment: Your SQL won't work because there is no space after `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Create your table in EF with code first. A simple lambda group by looks like:

```
List<MyRecord> myTable = new List<UserQuery.MyRecord>();
var items = myTable.GroupBy(t => t.MyColumn);

public class MyRecord
{
    public int MyRecordID { get; set; }
    public string MyColumn { get; set;}
}
```

The EF equivalent is, using the entity you created would be:

```
MyEntities dbContext = new MyEntities()
 using dbContext
 {
    var items = dbContext.MyTable // .. then a suitable lambda expression
 }
```